# Elementary Arithmetic Problem

Tags: elementary-number-theory, contest-math

In 1988, in a French math competition for middle school grades, the following problem was given:

*Complete this multiplication so that all the digits from 0 to 9 appear:*

$... × .. = ....1$

I am stumped. Of course the last digits of the two numbers are 3 and 7 but this is as far as I can go!
I am curious if there is a logical way to solve this problem without too much trial and error.

For the record, after significant experimentation my 3rd grade daughter has managed to obtain one solution, but this was pure luck.

Comment: Is it specifically a three digit number times a two digit number a five digit number?  The dots look like ellipses.

Comment: Writing a quick dirty script in javascript yields the only solution being `927 * 63 = 58401`

Comment: Don't know how much thes helps but if $abc\times de = fghi1$ the $(abc \mod 9)\times (de\mod 9) = fghi1\mod 9$ and $(a+b+c)\mod 9 + (f+g+h+i)\mod 9 = (f+g+h+i + 1)\mod 9$.... Also as $444\times 44 < 20000 $ there is a lower limit to what can work.

Comment: I don't yet have a quick argument for how to find this mentally or with minimal scratch work, but having seen the solution I notice that each of the three integers are divisible by $9$.  Perhaps that could be an approach, as if proving that each of the three terms must all have been divisible by $9$ in an easy method would limit the number of cases to check considerably as we'd then know combined with the earlier observation that the ones digits are $3$ and $7$ in the product respectively that the $2$-digit number must be $27$ or $63$

Comment: I was trying to figue with $(a+b+3,7)(d+7,3)=ad +bd +3,7d + 7,3a+7,3b +21 \equiv f+g+h+i+ 1\equiv 0+1+2+3+4+5+6+7+8+9 -(a+b+3+7+d)\equiv -a-b-d-1\pmod 9$ but I made an arithmetic error and... got frustrated and gave up.... But it had potential if I could fix the error.

Comment: Weird arithmetic error:  Somehow I figured if $de= 63$ then $a+b =8$ (which I'm wrong about... some error) yielding $807*63$ but what's weird is $807*63=50841$ which is very close to the correct solution of $927*63= 58401$.... Something is going on.... I just wish I could do this without making a dumb arithmetic error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the trick must be "casting out $9$'s."  Add the digits of the number.  If the result is greater than of equal to $9$, add the digits of the result, and so on, until you get a number less than $9$.  This gives the congruence class of the original number modulo $9$.

Let $x$ be the congruence class of the two-digit number, $y$ that of the three-digit number, and $z$ that of the five-digit number.  We know $$xy\equiv z\pmod9$$  Since the sum of the digit from $0$ to $9$ is $45$, we also know
$$x+y+z\equiv0\pmod9\\
xy\equiv-x-y\pmod9\\
(x+1)(y+1)\equiv1\pmod9$$

As you pointed out the last digits of the numbers on the left-hand side must be $3$ and $7$, which means that the number on the right-hand side must be at least $20451$.

If we know that the product of two numbers is congruent to $1\pmod9$ then the congruence classes of those numbers can only be:

- $1$ and $1$
- $2$ and $5$
- $4$ and $7$
- $8$ and $8$

I think you can put all this together to find the solution in fairly short order.  I'll give some examples of the kind of reasoning I have in mind.

First, suppose that the two-digit number ends in $3$.

$13$ isn't big enough to get a product of $20451$.

The digital root of $23$ is $5$ so $x+1=6$ and there's no possible value for $y+1$.

$33$ is inadmissible, so the two-digit number is $43$ or greater.  The digital root of $43$ is $7$ so $x+1=8$ and $y+1=8$, so $y=7$.  The first two digits of the three-digit number must sum to $9$.  The $1,3,4,7$ have already been used so the first two digits can only be $9$ and $0$ in that order.  However,$$43\cdot907=39001,$$ which doesn't work, so the two-digit number isn't $43$

The two-digit number isn't $53$ because then we'd have $x+1=9$ and there's no possible value for $y$.

If the two-digit number is $63$ then $x+1=1$, so $y+1=1$ and $y=0$.  The first two digits of the three-digit number must sum to $2$ or $11$.  If they sum to $2$ the number is $207$ which isn't big enough, so they sum to $11$.  We have used $1,3,6,7$, so the only possibility is $2$ and $9$.  The three-digit number must be $297$ or $927$.  The first is too small, since $$63\cdot297<63\cdot300=18900<20451$$  The second gives $$63\cdot927=58401$$ which is the answer.

One can continue in this manner test $73,83,93$ and the possibilities where the two-digit number ends in $7$ to show that the above is the only solution.

Comment: This is really good! Notice that from your congruences also follows that $z\equiv 0 $ or $z\equiv 4 \pmod9$ This can be used to further eliminate cases.

Answer (score 2):

The rule of nines:  $jkl \equiv j+ k + l \pmod 9$ so

So if we have $abc\times de = fghi1$ and $a,b,....,f,g,h,i,1$ are the digits from $0,....,9$ then $abc + de +fghi1 \equiv 0 \pmod 9$

And if $abc \equiv j\pmod 9$ and $de \equiv k \pmod 9$ we have $fghi1 \equiv jk \equiv -(j+k)$.

Or $(j+1)k \equiv -j$ and $(k+1)j \equiv -k$

Possible values for $j,k$.

$(0,0)$, $(1,4)$, $(3,6)$, $(4,1)$, $(6,3)$

Furthermore

$(a+b+c)(d+e) \equiv f+g+h+i+1 \equiv 0+1+2+3+4+5+6+7+8+9 - (a+b+c+d+e)\pmod 9$

$ad +bd +cd + ae +be +ce \equiv -a-b-c-d-e \pmod 9$

And as $\{c,e\} = \{7,3\}$ we have

$ad + bd +cd +ae +be + 21 \equiv -a-b-d -10\pmod 9$ so

$ad + bd + cd +ae + be +a+b+d \equiv 5\pmod 9$.

If $c=7;e=3$ we have

$ad + bd + 8d+3a+3b +a+b\equiv (a+b)(d+4)-d \equiv 5\pmod 9$

$(a+b)(d+4) \equiv 5+d\pmod 9$

Now $a+b+7\equiv a+b - 2\equiv j$ and $d+3\equiv k$ for $j,k$ above.

We can have

1)$a+b\equiv 2$ and $d= 6$
2)$a+b\equiv 3$ and $d= 1$ (impossible as $1$ is accounted for)
3)$a+b\equiv 5$ and $d= 3$ (ditto $3$)
4)$a+b\equiv 6$ and $d= 7$ (ditto $7$)
5)$a+b\equiv 8$ and $d= 0,9$.($d=0$ is impossible as $de$ is two digits)

Case 1: $a+b\equiv 2$ and $d=64

$(a+b) \equiv 2$.  As $a,b\ne 1,3,7,6$ we have $a+b=11$ and $a,b=2,9$

$(297,927)\times 63 = 18711, 58401$.

$927\times 63 = 58401$ is a working solution.

Case 2: $a+b \equiv 8$ and $d=9$.  As $a,b\ne 1,3,7,9;a\ne b$ we have $a+b=8$ and $a,b = 2,6$

$(267, 627)\times 93$ do not work.

If $c=3,e = 7$ we have

$ad + bd + cd +ae + be +a+b+d \equiv 5\pmod 9$.

$ad + bd + 3d + 7a + 7b + a+b+d\equiv 5\pmod 9$

$(a+b)d + 4d +8(a+b) \equiv (a+b)(d-1) -5d \equiv 5\pmod 9$ so

$(a+b)(d-1)\equiv 5(d+1)\pmod 9$.

$a+b+3 \equiv j$ and $d+7\equiv d-1\equiv k$ for $j,k=(0,0), (1,4), (3,6)$, (4,1), (6,3)$ above.

Which all lead to contradictions

1. $a+b\equiv 6$ and $d=1$ but $6*0\not \equiv 5*2$
2. $a+b\equiv 8$ and $d=5$ but $8*4\not \equiv 5*6$
3. $a+b\equiv 0$ and $d=7$ but $0*6\not \equiv 5*8$
4. $a+b\equiv 1$ and $d=2$ but $1*1 \not \equiv 5*3$
5. $a+b\equiv 3$ and $d=4$ but $3*2\not \equiv 5*5$

Answer (score 1):

If the numbers are $x$ ($3$ digits), $y$ ($2$ digits) and $z$ ($5$ digits) then we have the following deductions:

1. $x$ and $y$ end in $3$ and $7$.
2. $x$ and $y$ start with $4,5,6,8$ or $9$ (otherwise $z$ is too small).
3. $y \mod 9$ cannot be $2, 5$ or $8$ (otherwise $x + y + xy \not \equiv 0 \mod 9$).

This leaves $7$ possibilities for $y$:

$43, 63, 93, 57, 67, 87, 97$

and a total of $13$ possibilities for the pair $x,y$. Then I think you have to check each of these $13$ possibilities individually.

If the condition that $z$ ends in $1$ is removed then there are $9$ solutions, and $z$ can end in $0, 1, 4$ or $8$. The $9$ solutions break down as follows:

- $z$ ends in $0$ : $4$ solutions
- $z$ ends in $1$ : $1$ solution
- $z$ nds in $4$ : $1$ solution
- $z$ ends in $8$ : $3$ solutions